# React Components are not getting rendered in react routes

Tags: react-router-dom

I am trying to create a footer with react, but other components are not getting displayed when I click on the link in footer.

**Main.js**

```
const Main = () =>
(
    <main>
    <Switch>
       <Route path='/' component= {SearchPage}/>
       <Route path='/about' component={AboutPage}/>
       <Route path='/home' component={HomePage}/>
  </Switch>
     </main>

);
```

**Footer.js**

```
const Footer = () => {

    return (
        <footer>
        <div className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div className="container">
        <nav>
            <NavLink to="/home" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink> {" | "}
            <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">About Us</NavLink> {" | "} 

        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    </footer>

        );
```

**App.js**

```
const App = ()=>
(
    <div>
        <Main/>
        <Footer/>
  </div>
);
```

The problem is that components are not getting rendered if i click on the link.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Not meant as a slight, but it's hard to read the code when it's not formatted correctly. What happens when you click the link? Any error? Can you post the whole of the files? Could be something wrong with syntax or imports elsewhere?